# asp.net session expiring, even if the session values set in global.asax event session_start

Tags: asp.net, session

**`Global.asax`**

```
 void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {// Code that runs when a new session is started
        clsCommon.setRegisteredUserCountInSessionObject();
    }
```

**`clsCommmon`** ( class file )

```
public static void setRegisteredUserCountInSessionObject()
{
    string strSql = @"SELECT COUNT(id) FROM [canonweb].[dbo].[tbl_registeredUser_details] ru where ru.allowLogin='Y'";
    HttpContext.Current.Session["registeredUserCount"] = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(strConnectionString, CommandType.Text, strSql).ToString();        
}
```

**`countuser.aspx`** ( web page )

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Session["registeredUserCount"].ToString());
}
```

Sometimes `countuser.aspx` gives an error object reference not set to an instance of object.

If the session object does not exist, then `session_start` should fire and we should never get the above error.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is but given that data doesn't look like it is user specific it probably shouldn't be getting stored in session anyway. It would probably be btter to store it at the application level so you only need to get it once rather than for every new user browsing the site. Though of course there may be something about your particular situation that makes this the required way to do it.

Comment: What is the timeout setting for your session in web.config? If you session has died and you try to access a session variable, you will get an error.

Comment: Thanks Chris, the session timeout is 20 minutes. What is happening here is that we are displaying registered user count to all visitors on website. we do not want to make a DB count query for each page view so we are storing values in session so that there is only 1 DB hit per user. so we took this approach that for a single user the session_start event would fire only once regardless of the number of page views he does. strange thing happening is that the session value get created at session start and is lost by the time we reach page_load event of the page viewed